# Determine all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $GCD(n,48)=6$, $14|n$ and $|Div^+(n)|=12$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Determine all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(n,48)=6$, $14|n$ and $|Div^+(n)|=12$.

What I did: $14|n$ then $2|n$ and $7|n$ so $n=2\cdot7\cdot q$, $q \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $6|n$ implies $2|n$ and  $3|n$. This coupled with the earlier part means:

$n=2\cdot 3 \cdot 7 \cdot k$

$|Div^+(n)|=12=2\cdot2\cdot3=(1+1)(1+1)(2+1)$ means that $n$ has 3 (or less) prime factors .

So far $n=2^a3^b7^c$. $a+b+c=4$

$48=2^4\cdot3$ and $\gcd(n,48)=2\cdot3$ so $n$ has only one $2$ in it's prime factorization:

$n=2\cdot3^b7^c$; $a=1, b+c=3$.

I found no more restrictions so:
$$
n_1=2\cdot3^1\cdot7^2;n_2=2\cdot3^2\cdot7^1
$$

Is this correct?

Did I miss any $n$?

Comment: What does $Div^+(n)$ stand for?

Comment: @Mercy The set of all positive divisors of $n$.

Comment: It looks good to me!